# How can I unsplice a list of expression into code?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have an experiment for my project, basically, I need to *embedded* some s-expression into the code and make it run, like this,

```
(define (test lst)
    (define num 1)
    (define l (list))
    `@lst) ; oh, this is not the right way to go.

  (define lst
    `( (define num2 (add1 num))
      (displayln num2)))
```

I want the `test` function be like after `test(lst)` in racket code:

```
(define (test lst)
    (define num 1)
    (define l (list))
    (define num2 (add1 num)
    (displayln num2))
```

How can I do this in racket?

**Update**
The reason I would like to use `eval` or the previous questions is that I am using Z3 racket binding, I need to generate formulas (which uses racket binding APIs), and then I will fire the query at some point, that's when I need to evaluate those code.
I have not figured out other ways to go in my case...
One super simple example is, imagine
`(let ([arr (array-alloc 10)])`
`(array-set! arr 3 4))`

I have some model to analyze the constructs (so I am not using racketZ3 directly), during each analyzing point, I will map the data types in the program into the Z3 types, and made some assertions,

I will generate something like:

- At allocation site, I will need to make the following formula:

  `(smt:declare-fun arr_z3 () IntList)`
   `(define len (make-length 10))`
- Then at the array set site, I will have the following assertions and to check whether the 3 is less then the length

  `(smt:assert (</s 3  (len arr_z3)))`
  `(smt:check-sat)`
- Then finally, I will gather the formulas generated as above, and wrap them in the form which is able to fire Z3 binding to run the following gathered information as code:

  `(smt:with-context

       (smt:new-context)

       (define len (make-length 10))

       (smt:assert (</s 3  (len arr_z3)))
       (smt:check-sat))`

This is the super simple example I can think of... making sense?
*side note*. Z3 Racket binding will crash for some reason on version 5.3.1, but it mostly can work on version 5.2.1

Comment: From this plus your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428091/how-to-make-eval-work-on-define about using `eval`, it sounds like you want to write code at runtime? Could you help us understand what your'e trying to do? `eval` is likely not the best way to go about it.

Comment: @GregHendershott Is the edit in the question clear?

Comment: I just took a quick look at the N-Queens example for the Z3 package at https://github.com/sid0/z3.rkt/blob/master/examples/nqueens.rkt, and I don't see any reason why you'd need syntax-level stuff here; why does generating queries require eval? Can you provide a super-simple example of the way you want to formulate a query?

Comment: @JohnClements I have updated a simple example to show why and how I need to generate the formula and to evaluate them.

Comment: I see that you cross-posted to the racket-lang list, which I think is an *excellent* idea. I'm going to haul your explanation above over there, too, where I think you'll get good feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don’t understand what exactly you would like to achieve. To quote N. Holm, Sketchy Scheme, 4.5th edition, p. 108: »The major purpose of quasiquotation is the construction of fixed list structures that contain only a few variable parts«. I don’t think that quasiquotation would be used in a context like you are aiming at.

For a typical context of quasiquotation consider the following example:

```
(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(define sentence
  '(The square of))

(define (quasiquotes-unquotes-splicing x)
  `(,@sentence ,x is ,(square x)))

(quasiquotes-unquotes-splicing 2)
===> (The square of 2 is 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Warning: if you're not familiar with how functions work in Scheme, ignore the answer! Macros are an advanced technique, and you need to understand functions first.*

It sounds like you're asking about macros. Here's some code that defines `test` to be a function that prints `2`:

```
 (define-syntax-rule (show-one-more-than num)
   (begin 
     (define num2 (add1 num))   
     (displayln num2)))

 (define (test) 
   (define num1 1)
   (show-one-more-than num1))
```

Now, I could (and should!) have written `show-one-more-than` as a function instead of a macro (the code will still work if you change `define-syntax-rule` to `define`), but macros do in fact operate by producing code at their call sites. So the above code expands to:

```
 (define (test)
   (define num1 1)
   (begin 
     (define num2 (add1 num1))
     (displayln num2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the problem better, it's hard to say what the correct approach to this problem is.  A brute force approach, such as the following:

```
#lang racket

(define (make-test-body lst)

  (define source `(define (test)
                    (define num 1)
                    (define l (list))
                    ,@lst))
  source)


(define lst
  `((define num2 (add1 num))
    (displayln num2)))

(define test-source
  (make-test-body lst))

(define test
  (parameterize ([current-namespace (make-base-namespace)])
    (eval `(let ()
             ,test-source
             test))))

(test)
```

may be what you want, but probably not.