# How to make eval work on define?

Tags: scheme, racket

*I posted some other easy code, to clarify what's happening*

When I use `eval` on the following code

```
#lang racket
(define (test )
   `( (define num 1)
    (define l (list))
    (define num2 (add1 num))
      (displayln num2))) 

(eval (test) (make-base-namespace))
```

racket screams at me `define-values: not in a definition context in: (define-values (num) 1)`

My questions are:

- How to make `eval` work on definition?
- If `eval` is not designed to work on definitions, then is there some workarounds that can make it work?

I appreciate any help!

*I think this might be an alternative way to the thing I want to do in here: [How can I unsplice a list of expression into code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427979/how-can-i-unsplice-a-list-of-expression-into-code)*

Comment: Have you already read the http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html document?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
#lang racket
(define ns (make-base-namespace))
(define top-level-expressions
  '(begin 
     (define x 3)
     (+ x 1)))

(eval top-level-expressions ns)
```

Answer (score 1):

As racket tells you, `eval` needs an expression as argument. You should pass `'(define len (make-length 10))` to `eval`. Note the quote-sign `'`.

But I am not sure if you really need to do that, please read about the purpose and the flaws of [`eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil) first.